# Simple terminal progress bar in C++ (linux terminal)

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, progress-bar

I would like to make a progress bar in C++ that prints "Loading...".

The dots will be showed one per second.

Like **Loading** > **Loading.** > **Loading..** > **Loading...** .

How i can do this?

Thank you.

Comment: This would need to be a background process or separate thread then right? While your worker thread did stuff?

Comment: What do you mean thread? How i work in different threads?

Comment: This is a problem, cause you'll want this to print *while* something else is happening. So your code to update the output will need to be interleaved with the code that's actually doing the loading. If you have your loading code written it would be worth your time to add it to the question.

Comment: Are you familiar with `gotoxy()` function?
just try to write the dots each time and then clear them using a backspace character.

Comment: I am not familiar but i will search. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a thread to update every second the display.

Here a class to embed this:

```
#include <thread>   // for threads
#include <chrono>   // for expresssing duration
#include <atomic>   
#include <iomanip>
#include <functional>   // for std::ref()
using namespace std; 

class progress_bar {
    atomic<bool> finished; 
    atomic<int> n; 
    thread t;
public: 
    progress_bar() : finished(false),n(0), t(ref(*this)) { }    // initiate the bar by starting a new thread
    void operator() () {                                       // function executed by the thread
        while (!finished) {
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));   
            cout << "\rLoading" << setw(++n) << setfill('.') << " "; 
        }
    }
    void terminate() {                                  // tell the thread/bar to stop 
        finished = true;
        if (t.joinable())
            t.join(); 
    }
};
```

You may then use this class in your code:

```
progress_bar bar;
for (long i = 0; i < 3000000000L; i++);
bar.terminate();    // you can have a delay up to 1 s
```

The display is primitive:  the `\r` make the display restart at the begin of current line.  This works as long as you don't output anything else, and you have no more dots to display than length of line.

Alternatively, you can combine this with the curse answer, to write status to a fixed screen location more reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Ncurses library (though is ancient) is capable of emulating what you just said.

Comment: I want to print in gnome-terminal. I think this is different.